# How to manage >2MB object sizes in node.js

Tags: node.js, memory-management, size

I'm new to node.js - what object size limits do I need to worry about? I have a User object that reaches up to 10MB (stays server side) for user data processing. Are there any special issues I need to manage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about breaking it down in setters and getters and use promises to fulfil the requires when needed. I am sure you are not using all the properties at once.